# Can a sound or phoneme be an affix?

Tags: word-usage, phonetics, suffixes, prefixes

I was thinking that a sound or phoneme might go on, after, or before a word like the sound 'oh' going after the word 'that' or 'game' which might make the words 'thatoh' or 'gameoh'

So I thought or asked
Might a sound or phoneme be an affix?

Show if you understand what I wrote
Or let me know if you understand what I wrote

Comment: I think that *o* is a colloquialising suffix (*-o*), as in *convo, arvo, lesbo* etc.

Comment: I put the sound ‘oh' after the word 'game' or 'that' but I’m thinking you would put any sound after a word. Putting the sound ‘oh' after the word 'game' or 'that' was an example.

Comment: I understand that "oh" is just an example, but what do you mean by "Can it be an affix?"  You *can* put it after a word, if you want to.  Are you asking if we can *call* it an affix, or if it [functions like an affix](https://glossary.sil.org/term/affix-linguistics), or what?

Comment: Also, you might want to look up [Pig Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin) and [Double Dutch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutnese), because they are similar to what you want to do.

Comment: I’m sorry if I responded to you late and I was thinking if ‘oh’ after a word is an affix or if some call it an affix or what ‘oh’ after a word might be or what some might call it

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up different levels of language.  Here is map:

```
sounds -> phonemes ->   morphology -> syntax -> semantics -> pragmatics  
glyphs -> characters -/
```

A phoneme is a unit of spoken language. It is a recognisable sound. So in English, there are sounds /r/ and /l/  These are recognised as different by English speakers.  In written English, the equivalent is the "letter".

At the next level, phonemes are combined to make morphemes and an affix is a type of morpheme.  Examples are "un-" or "-ing".  It is possible for a morpheme to have just one phoneme (or just one character in written English).  For example in British English the morpheme "-er" is (often) a single phoneme /ə/ and the prefix "a-" is a single letter.

So an affix may be formed from a single phoneme. But you are mixing different levels of language and can become confused.

In the case of "-oh"  It is actually two phonemes /əʊ/.  It isn't a common suffix in English.  There is a suffix "-o" which forms colloquial forms, like "kiddo". But not "thato" or "gameo".

Sounds are sounds.  Sounds as recognised by speakers of a language are phonemes.  For example [r] and [l] have different sounds, and are different phonemes in English.  But in Japanese they are the same phoneme.  Japanese speakers literally can't hear a difference between fly and fry or right and light.  And phonemes aren't morphemes. Morphemes are elements that can be combined to make a word.  "-ing" is a morpheme so is "un-" and so is "cat".  When you combine one or more morphemes to make a word, and then one or more words to make a sentence: then you have "meaning".  And if you interpret that sentence in context, you have understanding!

Comment: What am I mixing up? Do all suffixes have meaning? And aren’t sounds phonemes?

Comment: I've edited to address this.  Sounds aren't phonenemes, and suffixes gain meaning by being placed in words which are placed in sentences, which are interpreted in context.

Comment: I thought “oh” would be one phoneme. Isn’t 'oh' one phoneme? Or why do you think 'oh' isn’t one phoneme?

Comment: "oh" is dipthong, a blend of two phonemes, in most pronunciations.  But the fact I need to mention "pronunciation" indicates how the phonemic and phonetic structure of the language are at a level below the morphological structure.

Comment: Aren’t diphthongs one sound? And I thought “oh” and “o” are the same sound so aren’t they the same sound?